# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in bundle.js:1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, package.json

I'm setting up boilerplate for react web apps and getting a blank page with the above console error when navigating to `http://localhost:3000`. I am a fresh bootcamp student and my knowledge of webpack config is very shallow, especially with lots of dependencies/babel setup in play. I reviewed responses to other users posting this issue, but it seems it can be caused by any number of issues around webpack config, and I'm worried about breaking things further while under a tight time constraint.

So I posted some of my code below. I am quite stuck- thanks for any pointers!

**public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>-= PROJECT TITLE PLACEHOLDER =-</title>
  <script src="/bundle.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app/index.js**

```
import '../public/style.css'
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './redux'
import Users from './components/Users'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Users />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
'use strict'

const { resolve } = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './app/index'],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  context: __dirname,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /jsx?$/,
        include: resolve(__dirname, './app'),
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "boilermaker",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "boilerplate for react-redux-express-sequelize app",
  "main": "server/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start-dev": "npm run build-watch & npm run start-server",
    "start-server": "nodemon --watch server -e js,html --ignore public server/index.js",
    "build-watch": "webpack -w",
    "start": "echo 'Running server for production - developers, use npm run start-dev for development' && node server/index.js",
    "seed": "node seed.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "redux",
    "skeleton"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "connect-session-sequelize": "^6.0.0",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^2.0.0",
    "pg": "^7.4.3",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "sequelize": "^4.37.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-fullstack": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-react", "react", "env", "stage-2"]
}
```

Comment: Your page is trying to load `http://localhost:3000/bundle.js`. What do you see when you visit that url in your browser? I suspect it's not the bundle, but an HTML response.

Comment: Thanks for responding @hughes - I managed to resolve this, it was a silly beginner's error (see my answer). But I reverted my fix temporarily to test your suggestion and let you know what I saw- it was the same issue, a blank page with the Unexpected Token error in console. Have a good weekend!

Answer (score 1):

This was ultimately due to a naive error where I put my static middleware *after* my HTML send in my Express router. I spotted it when a classmate asked to see my routing setup, at which point it jumped out at me. Thanks for reviewing, and sorry for the rookie mistake!

Comment: Was the change to the `babel-loader` rule required as well?

Comment: Hi @user1538301 - thanks for checking back in! I reverted the change to the `babel-loader` rule you recommended, and did not have any issues, so it doesn't appear to have been required to resolve this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `babel-loader` rule:

```js
{
  test: /(jsx|js)?$/, // you have app/index.js not app/index.jsx
  include: resolve(__dirname, './app'),
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: {
    presets: ['react']
  }
},
```

**EDIT:** Also I don't see the babel config in your `package.json` nor do I see a `.babelrc` so this is assuming that the config is in a `.babelrc` and properly set up for React/JSX (I see `babel-preset-react` in `package.json`; I am pretty sure you need that in your babel config).

Comment: Thank you and sorry- I neglected to post my .babelrc, it is added now.

i updated the babel-loader rule as you indicated, but am still having the issue. I am honestly confused at how the various babel dependencies work with webpack, it feels like I am chasing my tail at times :)

EDIT: I added babel-preset-react to .babelrc, but still receive the error in console. I will update my .babelrc in the original post to reflect what's in it now after adding this.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this error is because of `package.json` conflict. If you initiate a new `node` project inside a existing react folder, it might give this error. In this case try not to use `npm init` or `npm init -y`

Answer (score -1):

I believe your problem may be the ordering of your babel presets. They get applied from right to left.

So for example a .babelrc file in one of my projects looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```